# Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Given, a linked-list, I'm trying to partition it into so that the even nodes come before the odd nodes. My approach is to create two different linked-list (even and odd) to store even numbers and odd numbers. However, I'm running into a problem when I want to add to the even or odd linked list (I commented the part that I think is giving me problem in my code below). Thanks!

```
public class SeperateOddEven {

    static Node head;
    static int count;

    public static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        private Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
            count++;
        }

    }


    public void seperate() {

        Node even = null;
        Node odd = null;
        Node temp;

        // go through each linked-list and place node in new list depending on whether they are even or odd
        while(head != null) {
            // if even, place in even linked-list
            if(head.data % 2 == 0) {
                temp = new Node(head.data);
                even = temp; // Problem here
                even = even.next; // and here 
            } else { // if head.data % 2 != 0
                temp = new Node(head.data);
                odd = temp;
                odd = odd.next;
            }
            head = head.next;
        }

        toString(even);
        //toString(odd);

    }

    public void toString(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SeperateOddEven s = new SeperateOddEven();
        head = new Node(8);
        head.next = new Node(12);
        head.next.next = new Node(10);
        head.next.next.next = new Node(5);
        head.next.next.next.next = new Node(4);
        head.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(1);
        head.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(6);

        System.out.println("original list: ");
        s.toString(head);

        s.seperate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150609/how-to-arrange-all-even-numbers-in-front-of-odd-numbers-in-a-linked-list/36505517#36505517)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you identified exactly where the problem is.  Let's go line by line:

```
temp = new Node(head.data);
```

The extra `temp` variable is unnecessary but fine.

```
even = temp;
```

A problem arises on the next line however.  You assign `even` to `temp` (making temp unnecessary).  If something was previously stored in `even`, it is now lost to the garbage collector because you now have no reference to it.  `even` and `temp` are now both references to the same `Node` object.

What I think you might have wanted to do was to say `even.next = temp`.  This would start to create a list, but with only a single reference you would have to use that reference to point to the head of the list.  Each time you wanted to append to the list, you would need to loop through it until you found the end.  If you instead tried to make this single reference point to the tail of the list, you would no longer have any way to get back to the head because your `Node`s only have `next` references, and not `prev` references (a list with bidirectional references is called a doubly linked list).

```
even = even.next;
```

Because `even` (and `temp`) both point to the newly created `Node` object, the `even.next` property is `null`.  So when this line executes, `even` now points to null.  The work inside the loop has accomplished nothing because you immediately lose references to every `Node` you create.

Try something like this:

```
// Must keep track of head reference, because your Nodes can only go forward
Node evenHead = null;
Node evenTail = null;

Node oddHead = null;
Node oddTail = null;

while (head != null) {
    if(head.data % 2 == 0) {
        if (evenHead == null) {
            // The even list is empty, set the head and tail
            evenHead = new Node(head.data);
            evenTail = evenHead;
        } else {
            // Append to the end of the even list
            evenTail.next = new Node(head.data);
            evenTail = evenTail.next;
        }
    } else {
        // similar code for odd, consider creating a method to avoid repetition 
    }
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
while (head != null) {
            // if even, place in even linked-list
            temp = new Node(head.data);
            if (head.data % 2 == 0) {
                if(even == null) {
                    even = temp;
                } else{
                    Node insertionNode = even;
                    while(insertionNode.next != null) 
                        insertionNode = insertionNode.next;
                    insertionNode.next = temp;
                }


            } else { // if head.data % 2 != 0
                if(odd == null) {
                    odd = temp;
                } else{
                    Node insertionNode = odd;
                    while(insertionNode.next != null) 
                        insertionNode = insertionNode.next;
                    insertionNode.next = temp;
                }
            }
            head = head.next;
        }
```

Comment: This solution is very inefficient for reasons that I explain in my answer above.  By keeping a tail reference, you do not need to loop through the entire list with each insertion.  This solution is O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for sharing. I ended up using zposten's approach but yours works just as well.